Selling my home with minimal work
I am in the process of selling my home. The home has been in the family for over 60 years. A lot of the furniture is old. I am wondering if I should be showing it empty? or with old furniture?
I have interviewed several realtors and I have gotten different responses on this issue.
I am not opposed to taking out all the furniture but I do not want to put in new furniture. Also, I do not think I want to pick up the carpets which are not in good shape. Under the carpet, I have hardwood floors which I believe are in good shape but I am not sure of that,
Under what circumstances should a home be shown empty?

I'm not sure that this is answerable beyond the tautological "A home should be shown empty when the alternative will produce a lower price".  That's going to depend heavily on things like the exact state of the furniture-- does it make the place look run down or outdated-- whether an abundance of furniture makes the place look small, etc.  A realtor on the ground looking at the actual furniture and knowing the local market is best placed to make that sort of call.  If you've talked to several of those folks and received different answers, I'm not sure what internet randos can add.

There is not a definitive answer. Some buyers will like the house better with the "charm" of old furniture, and some may like it better empty (maybe envisioning their own furniture).
Same with the carpet - some may see the unfinished wood as a "project" and some may see the potential that is there. One thing you could to is check the properties that yours is compared to when determining the sales price - do they have carpet or wood floors? If they all have carpet then leave it. You can even use it as a selling point - "The carpet is good, but you always have the option of removing it and restoring the original wood floors"
I would not spend money to furnish it with new furniture - you're not going to get the cost of the furniture back in an increased sales price, and the buyers are just going to put in their own furniture anyway. If the old furniture is an eyesore and no one is using it, then I would get it out.
I have seen home listings that include an "allowance" for repairs or renovations, but that just increases the sales price by that amount. Meaning, you could list the home for $350k and include a $5k "allowance" for redoing the floors, instead of listing it for $354 "as-is". That also allows buyers to include the cost of the renovations in their loan instead of having to pay it upfront. You get the same amount at closing either way - it just means less that the buyers have to pay upfront. Talk to the realtor you choose to see if they know how to add this option correctly.

Trust the experience of the agent you pick. Besides explaining how they determined how much the house should be listed for, they will also develop a marketing plan.
They should identify what things need to be done before it goes on the market. They should explain shat needs to be done while the house is on the market, and what will happen end the end of the process.

I am not opposed to taking out all the furniture but I do not want to
put in new furniture.

Sometimes they want to put rented furniture into the house fro staging purposes. Sometimes people need to see a child's bed to know the room will work as a kids room. Sometimes they need to see a man cave to know it would work as a man cave. Other times they want it to be empty.

Also, I do not think I want to pick up the carpets which are not in
good shape. Under the carpet, I have hardwood floors which I believe
are in good shape but I am not sure of that.

They should explain the benefits and risks of each option. The options that come to mind include area runs, replacing the carpet and the pad, going with hardwood. Some are expensive, others are necessary, and others could be a waste of time.
The local agent knows the completion, and market. Explaining your options is part of the process of winning your business.

Some realtors will want the house empty so they can "dress" it (think of dressing a stage or movie set) with sparse furnishings that they think will show it to best advantages. Folks who use this approach usually obtain the furnishings used from sources like Freecycle, and dump them again after the house sells.
But it really depends on the house, the market, and how well what you currently have in it suits the image that you are trying to project to the potential buyers. Ask your broker to advise you. That is part of what they are getting paid for.
